# Advanced Custom Fields - display when specific template used?

Tags: templates, page-template, advanced-custom-fields

I know how to display my field groups on specific pages (display location: page is equal to myPage).

I have a few different templates on my site and would like to display Field Group X when the page is using template Y. Is this possible?

Comment: Has this question been resolved? Did my answer help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to give an exact answer without sharing your code, but using [`is_page_template()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/) in an `if` statement will help determine when you display your custom field group:

```
if ( is_page_template( 'template-y.php' ) ) {
    # Display Field Group X code here...
}
else {
    # Do something else...
}
```

Again, if you could provide your code, I can give you a better answer.

Comment: but what do  we put in the if section?  what code will 'display field group x code'

Answer (score 1):

You say you already know how to add fields. Once you add the metabox containing these fields add the following code. This will toggle the display of the metabox when the page template is changed. You'll need to change the metabox id and the file name of the page template that when selected, should show the metabox. Inspect the page to find the metabox id.

So if the metabox has an id of "metabox_id" and you want it to appear when the selected page template's file name is "template-file-name.php", use the following.

In functions.php

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_script');

function my_admin_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script('my-admin', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/js/custom-admin.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
}
```

In custom-admin.js

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#page_template').change(function() {
        $('#metabox_id').toggle($(this).val() == 'template-file-name.php'); //Change
    }).change();

    });
})(jQuery);
```